# apt mirror chooses wrong architecture

Tags: apt, repository, aptitude, architecture, apt-mirror

I tried to do a repository mirror using apt-mirror and it inexplicably choose the wrong architecture.

This is the architecture of the mirroring machine:

```
uname -a
Linux MyWorkStation 3.2.0-76-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 22:16:09 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

head /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5690  @ 3.47GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x10
cpu MHz         : 3458.056
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 0
```

This is what my /etc/apt/mirror.list looks like:

```
############# config ##################
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

The mirror that was created was only amd64 binaries, no i386. Where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `uname -a` output shows that the mirroring machine IS amd64, and the default of `set defaultarch  <running host architecture>` says to mirror amd64.

Try either adding `deb-i386` lines (that otherwise duplicate the `deb` lines) or changing the `deb` lines to `deb-i386`.

Unless you're very short on disk space, i'd recommend adding rather than changing - you've already mirrored amd64 and you might need it in future (and you can use it to upgrade or install packages on your `apt-mirror` host itself), so why delete it?

Comment: How can it be amd64? Its a workstation with 4x Intel Xeon CPUs. Xeon is not amd is it? Are you saying x86_64 means amd64? If so, how can it be amd64 if the machine is Xeon machine?

Comment: `amd64` is the generic name for 64 bit x86 because AMD invented it (and then licensed it to Intel when Intel finally admitted that their 64-bit Itanium architecture was a mistake).  `amd64` later became known as `x86-64` (or `x86_64`), but debian (and `gcc`, and probably other distros and compilers) didn't change the arch name because it would break existing code and makefiles (and maybe because they didn't feel like giving in to intel marketer lobbying...dunno about that for sure).  also, changing the arch name would case a mirror flood as all the mirrors downloaded the same files again.

Comment: hmm, ok maybe I am ok then; if I do lscpu on both machines I get the same thing: x86_64. Does that mean the amd64 binaries should work on the remote machine? I mean if the lscpu output matches, then they should use the same mirror?

Comment: yes.  so you're back to what i said about getting the `file:/` path right in your sources.list.    BTW, IIRC, in your other question, your `sources.list` mentions `trusty`, but here you seem to be mirroring `precise`....that's probably the problem right there.

Comment: Well, the mirroring machine is precise apparently and the offline machine is trusty. Will this create a problem? Do I need to redo the mirror for trusty?

Comment: yes.  you'll need to mirror trusty for the off-line machine.  or both precise and trusty if you want the mirror to work for both machines (or upgrade the precise machine to trusty too - or upgrade them both to wily or xenial).

Comment: ok, I can see that the mirror.list on the connected machine specifies its own release (precise), but since the offline is trusty, I guess I need to redo the mirror for trusty.

Comment: add lines for trusty rather than change the existing lines if you want to keep the existing precise mirror for the mirroring host's use.  and if you want the trusty mirror to be completely separate (e.g. for copying on to a USB drive for use by the offline trusty machine), use a different `apt-mirror` config file that specifies a different `mirror_path`, otherwise both `precise` and `trusty` packages will be in the same `pool/`` directory tree.